# Angular 2 Custom Pipe Explanation

Tags: angular

I've been slowly learning Angular 2 and recently I've been trying to implement a custom pipe to filter my gallery results by category. All the articles I read don't really go into detail about what is actually happening in a custom pipe and I'm confused how to construct my own.

Here is some code from a tutorial I was looking at, I think the code is a little dated but I imagine the principal is the same.

```
import {Pipe} from 'angular2/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'AgePipe'
})
export class AgePipe {

  transform(value, args?) {
    let [minAge] = args;
    return value.filter(person => {
      return person.age >= +minAge;
    });
  }

}
```

I imagine the value and args are set when the pipe is implemented. I keep getting a TS errors for both value and args saying "parameter 'value' implicitly has 'any' type".

Comment: The pipe is implicitly fed the left hand argument `X | AgePipe` as the value by the template compiler. The template compiler will also take anything after the colon on the right as the args value for the transform `X | AgePipe: '21'`

Answer (score 2):

This typescript error is caused by the fact that you configured the typescript compiler to disallow implicit any. I.e. you're supposed to explicitly specify the type of your variables, and explicitly specify the any type if that's the type you want, instead of relying on typescript to implicitly infer the any type. See `--noImplicitAny` in the [TypeScript documentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

Note that Angular2 chose not to include a filter pipe because they think it's a bad idea: such an operation is too costly to be done repeatedly by the view, and it should be done only when needed by the component.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have read that filter pipes are a bad idea due to speed. My application is fairly simple and small so I don't think its an issue but I would like to know if there is a better way of implementing what I want to do. I have a navbar at the top that has 4 categories (Design, Web Design, Photography, Fine Art). I list all my projects in an array of thumbnails on my home page and I want to allow the user to click on the links in the nav to filter the array to each category if they like. Is there a better way to implement this outside of a filter?

Comment: Yes. Just call a method of the component when the link is clicked, filter the original array in your component and save it to a field of your component. Iterate through this filtered array in your view.